# What can cause a reduction in frame rate when upgrading a graphics card?

Tags: c++, hardware, directx

We have a two-screen DirectX application that previously ran at a consistent 60 FPS (the monitors' sync rate) using a NVIDIA 8400GS (256MB). However, when we swapped out the card for one with 512 MB of RAM the frame rate struggles to get above 40 FPS. (It only gets this high because we're using triple-buffering.) The two cards are from the same manufacturer (PNY). All other things are equal, this is a Windows XP Embedded application and we started from a fresh image for each card. The driver version number is 169.21.

The application is all 2D. I.E. just a bunch of textured quads and a whole lot of pre-rendered graphics (hence the need to upgrade the card's memory). We also have compressed animations which the CPU decodes on the fly - this involves a texture lock. The locks take forever but I've also tried having a separate system memory texture for the CPU to update and then updating the rendered texture using the device's UpdateTexture method. No overall difference in performance.

Although I've read through every FAQ I can find on the internet about DirectX performance,  this is still the first time I've worked on a DirectX project so any arcane bits of knowledge you have would be useful. :)

One other thing whilst I'm on the subject; when calling Present on the swap chains it seems DirectX waits for the present to complete regardless of the fact that I'm using D3DPRESENT_DONOTWAIT in both present parameters (PresentationInterval) and the flags of the call itself. Because this is a two-screen application this is a problem as the two monitors do not appear to be genlocked, I'm working around it by running the Present calls through a threadpool. What could the underlying cause of this be?

Comment: You may have been tricked to buy the 65nm "rev. 2" version which has only 8 shader units instead of 16. That said, why do you use a 8400GS if you can have a GT610 with 4x the memory and DDR3 instead of DDR2, and 4x the number of shader units for the same price? (plus, it has a TDP of only 29W vs 40W)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the cards exactly the same (both GeForce 8400GS), and only the memory size differ? Quite often with different memory sizes come slightly different clock rates (i.e. your card with more memory might use slower memory!).

So the first thing to check would be GPU core & memory clock rates, using something like [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/).

Answer (score 1):

It's an easy test to see if the surface lock is the problem, just comment out the texture update and see if the framerate returns to 60hz.  Unfortunately, writing to a locked surface and updating the resource kills perfomance, always has.  Are you using mipmaps with the textures? I know DX9 added automatic generation of mipmaps, could be taking up a lot of time to generate those.  If your constantly locking the same resource each frame, you could also try creating a pool of textures, kinda like triple-buffering except with textures.  You would let the render use one texture, and on the next update you pick the next available texture in the pool that's not being used in to render.  Unless of course your memory constrained or your only making diffs to the animated texture.

Comment: Mipmaps are disabled. I'll try double-buffering the dynamic textures and see what happens. Thanks.